# Which tense to use when I want to state a fact in a running text primarily used in the past tense

Tags: tense

context:
[1] I did a survey yesterday on how students find their study partner. Some students responded that
they preferred finding their partner through the internet. It was/is easy that way.
[2] We went to Shanghai last year. Shanghai is/was the biggest city in China with over 20 million
population.

Are both Okay or is their a grammar rule that I should be aware? If both are OKay, would a native speaker tells me which one sounds better to the ear? Thanks in advance for the time.

Answer (score 0):

First sentence: it **was** easy that way. "It" refers to the **past** action of students finding their study partner. They would probably have used "this way" instead of "that way" to refer to finding their study partner in general.

Second sentence: Shanghai **is** the biggest city in China with over 20 million population. This is a generally true statement. Using "was" may implies this statement does not hold at present.